# OData services with Elastic search

Tags: elasticsearch, odata

I am new to OData services.I have written a query to retrieve the specific field with null values.I build the query in OData and pass it on to elastic search to retrieve data.But the query seems to be not working.

```
The query is as follows:
$filter=assignedToEM eq  null.
I have also tried giving as: $filter=assignedToEM eq  'null'

The query has been built as :
{
 "from" : 0,
 "size" : 15,
 "query":{
       "bool" : {
           "must_not" : {
                    "term" : {
                        "assignedToEM" : "null"
                               }
                         }
                 }
          }
 }
In elastic search schema,The not_null value for assignedToEM is given as "_null_".

It would be really helpful if i get a solution for this as soon as possible.
Thanks.
```

Comment: Since no accept answer was found.
I think the query will be $filter=assignedToEM eq  null

and you can build the ES query with missing field
https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/1.4/query-dsl-missing-filter.html

Answer (score 0, accepted):

One way to achieve this would be to create a [`query_string` query](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/query-dsl-query-string-query.html?q=query_str#query-string-syntax) with the special `_missing_` field name instead, like this:

```
{
    "from": 0,
    "size": 15,
    "query": {
        "query_string": {
            "query": "_missing_:assignedToEM"
        }
    }
}
```

Or what should also work is to use the `NOT` operator like this:

```
{
    "from": 0,
    "size": 15,
    "query": {
        "query_string": {
            "query": "NOT(assignedToEM:*)"
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Please correct me if I am wrong.Missing and exists filter is used in elastic search right? Since the query is built on OData side,Is it ok to use the same filter?

Comment: What I understood from your question is that you'd like to "translate" an OData `eq null` filter into the equivalent Elasticsearch filter. What I suggest does exactly that.

Comment: Thanks.This code worked.And I had to make some more          modifications in the code on ODataService side to make it work.

Answer (score 2):

Use [Olastic](https://github.com/Hevelian/hevelian-olastic) - open source implementation of the OData services for Elasticsearch.
You can use sources as an example or get dependency from [maven](https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/com.hevelian.olastic/olastic-core)

Comment: taras - its a great design but I wonder if you are planning to update it soon ?

Comment: @bigbadmouse yes, we will update it, but I suppose not in the near future

Comment: I'd be happy to try if you can assist me with some questions ?

Comment: sure, I will help.

Comment: thanks - I don't mind doing the work and I'm happy to share after, but I could use some pointers (no pun)